# on click on "ONLY" all input text unchecked and current one should get checked

Tags: jquery

I hover on class `".airportdetails"` and text only is get appear now if i click on whole div input get checked  bt i want i i click on only then all other get unchecked and only current will get check

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/VRE9n/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".airportdetails").mouseover(function() {
    $("li a", this).show();
}).mouseout(function(){
$("li a", this).hide();
});
})

$('.airportdetails').click( function() {
    var $newcheck = $(this).find(":checkbox");
    if (!$newcheck.prop("checked") ) {
        $newcheck.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $newcheck.prop("checked", false);
    }
});
$('.airportdetails input').click(
    function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `$(":checkbox").prop("checked", false);` at the begging of the click function to find any checked boxes and uncheck them.

```
$('.airportdetails').click( function() {
    $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    var $newcheck = $(this).find(":checkbox");
    if (!$newcheck.prop("checked") ) {
        $newcheck.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $newcheck.prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VRE9n/5/

Comment: actully i want to check multiple checkbox bt if i click on text "only" it should get check and other should get unchecked

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('.airportdetails').click( function() {
var $allcheck = $('.airportdetails ul li').find(":checkbox");
if (!$newcheck.prop("checked") ) {
    $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    $newcheck.prop("checked", true);
} else {
    $newcheck.prop("checked", false);
}
});
```